# Calculating the length of a belt on a roll

Tags: trigonometry

I work at a shop that has conveyor belts. When we get a belt of unknown length, we count the number of wraps (red) and measure the core height (green) The core is shown in grey. I was told that the length of a belt can be calculated from the core height and the number of wraps.

[image: belt diagram]

[Code used to generate image.](https://gist.github.com/smeschke/a851dc7c34adc0f830aa51da602af508)

I have forgotten the exact formula for this calculation! So I wrote a short Python script to to figure it out.

The script I wrote produces a spiral made of line segments, and the summed distance of the line segments is 8500. The length of the green line in 325, and there are 8 wraps around the core. These are unit-less quantities.

belt length = core height * number of wraps * pi

I know this is not the formula we use at work. What is the best way to approximate belt length given core height and number of wraps?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for an [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral)?

Comment: Do you know the length radius of the grey core and the distance  between any two consecutive red numbers?

Comment: If $R$ is the radius of the core and $d$ is the width of the spiral then your spiral has equation in polar form $$r=\frac{d}{2\pi}\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+R$$ The domain of your spiral is $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \theta \leq \frac{31\pi}{2}.$ You can calculate the length of the spiral by using arc length formula.